# ExpressionEngine Search not working with Matrix

Tags: matrix, search

I have a list of files in a Matrix field. here is a screenshot of it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QC9Y.jpg

So we have a file_title of 'Form 1' and when I search for Form I get the EE error page that says no Results Found. Even when searching for Form 1 verbatim I get the same result.

Just to be concise here is the code for the search box:

```
{exp:search:simple_form search_in="everywhere" result_page="site/search-results" status="not closed" where="all" show_expired="yes" show_future_entries="yes"} 
                <input type="image" src="/img/search-input.jpg" alt="Hunt" class="button" />
                <input type="text" name="keywords" id="header_s" class="text" maxlength="100" /> 
            {/exp:search:simple_form}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you switch this to a textarea, does it find it?  Just some quick, basic troubleshooting.

Comment: There is no listing of `textarea` under the Wygwam items - just: Date,File,Playa,P&T Checkboxes,P&T Dropdown,P&T List,P&T Multiselect,P&T Pill,P&T Radio Buttons,P&T Switch,SafeCracker File,StructureFrame,Text,Wygwam

Comment: Text is the same thing as textarea in Matrix as long as you check "multiline"

Comment: Will checking that box have any adverse effects on the content already stored there?

Comment: @coldcoder Always backup your DB before making changes like this one to make sure you can get back if there are adverse affects. We can never be 100% certain.

Comment: For the record, this is a Matrix field, not a WYGWAM field. Can you edit your question?

Comment: Thanks for the edit to those that did them, I mis-read the name {wygwam} on the wrong input. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matrix’s “Is col searchable?” setting doesn’t take effect until you re-save your entries. If you’ve got a lot of entries, check out [this script](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/3514/490) which will loop through all of your entries and re-save them for you.

Answer (score 1):

First thing is to add the `channel=""` [**parameter**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/search/simple.html#channel) to your search tag with the short name of the channel or channels that needs to be searched.

Other things to check:

1. Is the entry containing this data set to closed?
2. Does the entry containing this data have an expiration date set that has passed?
3. Does the entry containing this data have an entry date that is set for the future?