# Matrix & Simple Search

Tags: matrix, pixelandtonic, simple-search

I'm trying to search inside 'Matrix' cols with Simple Search module - but it's just not happening.

I've ensured that the field is 'Searchable' and that all columns in the Matrix are 'Searchable' also. The entries themselves are not closed & not in the future - but they still won't show up in the search results.

This is the code I have for the Simple Search form:

```
{exp:search:simple_form result_page="search/results" no_result_page="search/no-results" results="10" channel="shop_product" where="all" search_in="everywhere"}
        <ul>
            <li><input type="text" name="keywords" /></li>
            <li class="submit-btn"><input type="image" src="{site_url}assets/images/icon-search.png" width="32" height="32" name="search"/></li>
        </ul>
{/exp:search:simple_form}
```

Any ideas why this wouldn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've enabled the searchable columns for the Matrix field while there were existing entries, you'll have to save each of those entries in order to make it work. Basically, the searchable content needs to be put in the `exp_channel_data` table, which Matrix does upon saving entries.

Comment: Ouch. Okay, is there a way to save all entries in to exp_channel_data? The site has over 500 entries... Bit too much opening each one and saving it again.

Comment: There might be a script/query available somewhere. Better ask P&T.

Comment: There is indeed a script: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/3510/how-can-i-bulk-update-the-matrix-search-index-without-re-saving-each-entry/3514#3514