# Can Super Search search categories in a matrix fieldtype?

Tags: matrix, categories, supersearch

Let me start out by saying that I am using Super Search 2.1.3 and on EE version 2.7.3.

Here is my problem. I have a channel for each product I'm selling. Each product has a Matrix field that can have several "variations" on that product and is really the meat of the data about the product itself. For instance, let's say the product is a particular table for this example. The variations for that table would be "Solid Top Table" and "Extension Table". Each variation would have a series number, product number, dimensions, categories etc. I'm using WB Category Select (1.3.5) to simply associate my categories with each matrix row, which is the important part because it's what my question is all about.

Can I use Super Search to search for the categories associated with each Matrix row for that product variation and, essentially, the product as a whole?

From what I've read this does not seem possible, however if someone has any ideas it would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahmad, thank you for your response. I edited what I originally stated above to move it into an actual answer. The fields did need to be checked again to verify that they were truly searchable.

However, now that they are I have found that some fields will be included in the search results while the categories do not get included in the search. From my testing there is no way to search for a WB Category field in a Matrix field using EE or the Super Search plugin. The way the data is stored using WB Categories, the IDs are displayed in the matrix data instead of the actual category text.

So, the answer is that the EE or Super Search plugin will check any searchable Matrix field, but the data obviously wasn't what I was expecting so the search results were different as well.

Answer (score 1):

a lot of custom fields here.

I don't know about Super Search , but for EE search you can search in Matrix data if you mark the field as searchable as mention here;

[Matrix & Simple Search](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/11252/matrix-simple-search)

I hope this will help you.

Regard's.