# Playa Title Changes and Native Search

Tags: playa, search

Using Playa setup in a standard way… (ex. I have a channel of Videos and a channel of Papers. In the Video entry, the admin has a playa where they drag over any related Papers.)

The issue I've noticed is that if there is a change to a Paper's Title, the related Video's searchable data doesn't pick up that change (ex. have an existing relationship between Video/Paper, change the paper title, the new title will be right when output in the template, but native search does not reflect the new title where it's related — so a search for the new title doesn't help you find the video.)

This makes sense as my understanding is that:
* You create a relationship in an entry
* When you save that entry Playa copies the Title of the related item into exp_channel_data for search purposes

The problem is I need to make sure that exp_channel_data gets updated when that related title of the related item changes to keep native search working correctly.

Has anyone else run into this/found a workaround? The only thing I've found is to re-save all the entries after a Title change, but that's really not a sustainable fix :/

Tks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've run up a test and can confirm this bug.

Additionally I can see that if you edit/submit (no change) the parent (playa holding) entry the child title is updated.

So in order to fix I beleive the easiest approch would be to develop an extension, look for entry_saved events on entries with ID's that are in the `exp_playa_relationships.child_entry_id` column, and if so 'touch' the parent too.

And of course, report it to P&T as a bug...

Related Posts : [How can I bulk update the Matrix search index without re-saving each entry?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/3510/how-can-i-bulk-update-the-matrix-search-index-without-re-saving-each-entry) (same effect, different module!)

Found a nice little bit o info to help you out, you'll have to create your extension, hook the `entry_submission_end` event in your extension, then you'll need a function like this :

```
function _ChekcUpdateParentChannelData($entryId, $meta){
    $res = ee()->db->select('parent_entry_id')
                   ->where('child_entry_id', $entryId)
                   ->get('playa_relationships');
    if ( $res->num_rows() > 0 ) {
        //aha, this is a child entry, get all the children of the parent!
        //you'll need to fetch ALL the child entry_id's, url_titles and 
        //Titles, assuming we have these in an array now called $children

        //from ft.playa.php line 2714, this is the code that sets the channel_data table
        $keywords = "";
        foreach ($children as $entry)
        {
            $keywords .= ($keywords ? "\n" : '') . "[{$entry['entry_id']}] [{$entry['url_title']}] ".str_replace('\'', '', $entry['title']);
        }

        //we now have a data to stick back into the channel_data
        //so here write an update query, where entry_id = parent 
        //entry_id set the field_XX to $keywords 

    }
}
```

Lots to fill in there, but you should get there. Let us know if you contact P&T and if they are going to patch or not. If they don't I might be inclined to write a 3rd party utility for this, and also for grid n matrix too if they still exhibit the same behaviour!

Comment: Thanks for running a test to confirm. I have a bug report into P&T and will let you know what I hear (if they don't post here directly).

Comment: Thanks for the update, out of curiosity, did you ever try rolling your own baed onthe snippet above? If not did you get a solution / workaround?? P&T do visit this board regularly (Brandon usually!) so they may spot this here too.

Comment: Just heard from P&T this morning, and haven't done anything on my side yet. They said that the quickest solution would be to write an extension (read as: it doesn't sound like they intend to tackle this on their side). Do you think you'll be writing a utility for this? If so maybe I can be your first user :)